# I wrote down my 12 words before uninstalling my app. I put them in after reinstalling the app and it gives name a different wallet address, why i?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-recovery, recover-private-key

I’ve tried to put the 12 words in different wallets and it keeps changing the wallet address

Comment: Does the new address by any chance start with a different letter?

Answer (score 1):

Current wallets create a new address every time you ask them. This is to improve your privacy.

The wallet keeps track of all these addresses.

If you restore a Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) wallet from a seed phrase it can generate exactly the same set of addresses. That is the "deterministic" part.

You must make sure the wallet is configured to use the same "derivation path" and type of address e.g. Segwit  ...